# exit from function if not return value within 30 seconds java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some java code to send sms .
It will return a delivery report within 15 seconds in many times.(but some times it not happened)
I want to stop that sms sending functions if it not give a delivery report withing 15 seconds.
If u can, please give an similar sample code for that or
 give some links that should i read to do that. 
Thank You very much...!

`

```
public String  sendTest(String port )

{

modemName = "Huwawi";
    bitRate = 115200;
    modemPin = "0000";
    SMSC = "+94785000008";  try {
        OutboundMessage msg;
        OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway(id, "COM1", bitRate, modemName, "E17u-1");
        gateway.setInbound(true);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        gateway.setSimPin(modemPin);

        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);

        Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);


        Service.getInstance().startService();

        msg = new OutboundMessage("+94710433607", "test successful !");

        Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

       OutboundMessage.MessageStatuses status = msg.getMessageStatus();


       System.out.println(msg.getMessageStatus());

        Service.getInstance().stopService();
        Service.getInstance().removeGateway(gateway);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex.getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber() == 189) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Port currently owned by usb Modem's application. \n Please close it & run the programm again.",
                    "Port Exception",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    ex.getMessage(),
                    "Sending faile",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }return port;
}
```

`
If i give a wrong port number the code is stuck from

```
Service.getInstance().startService();
```

If i give correct port number the delivery report is received before 15 seconds.

If i give wrong port number,code doesn't give or return any value.
If code not return a value within 15 seconds , i know that port number is wrong one.
so i want a help to close the function automatically if it not return a value within 15 seconds.
thanks again...!

Comment: so u r asking us to do ur homework?

Comment: Tell what you have tried till now. Try something, if you get in trouble then there are many to help at SO. But key is you should try first.

Comment: Where is it stuck? Within Java code, from the description, I doubt? While running SQL, then which database? External commands on the host? Not enough information to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a thread, and stop it if nothing happen under 15s. 
I mean something like this :

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         // Send SMS
    }
}
t.start();
// ...
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(true)
{
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time > 15000)
         t.stop();
}
```

I hope you get what i said

Comment: Note that `Thread.stop` is deprecated because it is inherently unsafe:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html If you have the possibility, fix the blocking code or try to find out if there is a safer way to unblock it in your concrete case (e.g. by interrupting its `Thread.sleep` and modifying some attributes so it doesn't go back to sleep).